# The declared type of navigation property Project.Models.Customer.SubCustomers is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I have had a look at answers to similar errors, but I can't seem to find an answer to my particular error.

I am running a migration and the error happens when the seed method is run (migration has worked fine).

> The declared type of navigation property Project.Models.Customer.SubCustomers is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation.

This is for a circular reference, i.e. a Customer can have 0..* SubCustomers and 0..1 ParentCustomers.

Customer model:

```
public class Customer : Entity
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Relationships

    public int? ParentCustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> SubCustomers { get; set; } // a Customer has many Customers as SubCustomers, a Customer has zero or one ParentCustomer

    // Other relationships
}
```

From context fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(customer => customer.CustomerId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(customer => customer.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(500);
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>() // a Customer has many Customers as SubCustomers, a Customer has zero or one ParentCustomer
            .HasOptional(customer => customer.SubCustomers)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(customer => customer.ParentCustomerId);
```

From seed method: (the customers are created in the database, sub-customers does not work)

```
// Default Customers - create and save
var customers = new[]{
    new Customer { Name = "Custa" },
    new Customer { Name = "Custb" },
    new Customer { Name = "Custc" }
};
context.Customers.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, customers[0], customers[1], customers[2]);
context.SaveChanges();

// Add SubCustomers b & c to Customer a (ids calculated beforehand, e.g. aId, as linq does not support array index)
var aId = customers[0].CustomerId;
var a = context.Customers.Include(c => c.SubCustomers).SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == aId);
if (a.SubCustomers == null)
    a.SubCustomers = new List<Customer>();
var bId = customers[1].CustomerId;
var b = a.SubCustomers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == bId);
if (b == null)
    a.SubCustomers.Add(context.Customers.Single(c => c.CustomerId == bId));
var cId = customers[2].CustomerId;
var c = a.SubCustomers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == cId);
if (c == null)
    a.SubCustomers.Add(context.Customers.Single(c => c.CustomerId == cId));
context.SaveChanges();
```

If anyone can spot what is causing the error I would be very grateful. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally figured this out after a bit of reading and trial and error. I was getting confused, because it was self referencing, and leaving out a crucial element.

Normally, when creating a one-to-many relationship, between two different objects, you would have something like the following:

```
public class Foo {
    public int FooId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // Relationships
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;} // a Foo has many bars, a Bar has one optional Foo
}

public class Bar {
    public int BarId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // Relationships
    public int? FooId {get; set;} // a Foo has many bars, a Bar has one optional Foo
    public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}
}
```

Then in the context (fluent API):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>() // a Foo has many bars, a Bar has one optional Foo
    .HasRequired(bar => bar.Foo)
    .WithMany(foo => foo.Bars)
    .HasForeignKey(bar => bar.FooId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
            .HasKey(bar => bar.BarId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasKey(foo => foo.FooId);
```

In my code, in my original question, I had left out the equivalent of `public virtual Foo Foo {get; set;}` in this case.

So to create a self-referencing Foo you need all three elements of the relationship, that are split between two objects in the example above, to be in the Foo object (pretty logical really!):

```
public class Foo {
    public int FooId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    // Relationships
    public int? ParentFooId {get; set;} // a Foo has many SubFoos, a Foo has one optional ParentFoo
    public virtual Foo ParentFoo {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> SubFoos {get; set;}
}
```

And the context (fluent API):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>() // a Foo has many SubFoos, a Foo has one optional ParentFoo
    .HasOptional(foo => foo.ParentFoo)
    .WithMany(foo => foo.SubFoos)
    .HasForeignKey(foo => foo.ParentCustomerId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasKey(foo => foo.FooId);
```

To seed data into this self referencing relationship I would need the following in Configuration.cs:

```
// Default Foos - create
var foos = new[]{
        new Foo { Name = "foo1", SubFoos = new List<Foo>() },
        new Foo { Name = "foo2", SubFoos = new List<Foo>() },
        new Foo { Name = "foo3", SubFoos = new List<Foo>() },           
context.Tabs.AddOrUpdate(t => t.View, foos[0], foos[1], foos[2]);
context.SaveChanges();

// Add a SubFoo to a Foo
var parentFooId = foos[0].FooId;
var parentFoo = context.Foos.Include(f => f.SubFoos).SingleOrDefault(f => f.FooId == parentFooId);
// If no current SubFoos initiate an empty list
if (parentFoo.SubFoos == null)
    parentFoo.SubFoos = new List<Foo>();
// Get another Foo to add as a SubFoo
var childFooId = foos[1].FooId;
// Check if child foo already exists and add if not
var childFoo = parentFoo.SubFoos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.FooId == childFooId);
if (childFoo == null)
    parentFoo.SubFoos.Add(context.Foos.Single(f => f.FooId == childFooId));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this question and answer. We've been struggling with this exact problem this morning for a few hours, and this was the post that pointed us in the right direction. Thank you.